# Getting max revision number from a view is not working as I thought?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

Using MySQL 5.6.  I have a view that grabs from one main table called `listquotes`, and a few other items from other tables.  The import columns in the table that are also in the view are `Quote #` and `Revision`.  We might have 5 different revisions of the same quote number, so our table would look like

```
id   ....   Quote#     Revision
================================
1           1234       1
2           1234       2
3           1234       3
4           1234       4
5           1234       5
```

Now on my application GUI we have a dropdown that should allow you to only see the most recent revisions of every quote.  Here's how I try to do that

```
SELECT
...columns...
FROM view_allQuoteInfo
LEFT JOIN listcustomers c ON c.id = view_allQuoteInfo.customerId
WHERE 1=1  AND view_allquoteinfo.customerId = 2453  AND view_allquoteinfo.quoteStatusId = 2 AND view_allquoteinfo.Revision = (SELECT max(t.Revision) FROM view_allquoteinfo t WHERE view_allquoteinfo.`Quote #` = t.`Quote #`)
ORDER BY idx DESC
```

However, this is not giving me the results I want.  Here's an analysis for tihs specific customer I did in excel, some quotes that only have one revision are not showing up like 6668 while others like 4730 which has two revisions is working properly

[image]

The where clause for the All table in excel is

```
    1=1 
AND view_allquoteinfo.customerId = 2453  
AND view_allquoteinfo.quoteStatusId = 2
```

and the clause for the Latest Table is

```
    1=1  
AND view_allquoteinfo.customerId = 2453  
AND view_allquoteinfo.quoteStatusId = 2 
AND view_allquoteinfo.Revision = 
       (SELECT max(t.Revision) 
          FROM view_allquoteinfo t 
         WHERE view_allquoteinfo.`Quote #` = t.`Quote #`)
```

the only difference being me trying to get the mlatest revision.  The logic looks right to me but obviously MySQL is not interpreting it the way I thought it would.

Any clue as to why it's not working or how I would fix it?

I would expect to see quote 6668 revision one and quote 5963 revision 4 in my "Latest" table, while quote 5963 revision 1,2,3 would not be there.

Comment: Trust me I hate it too, but I inherited it like this, it's used all over our application, and unfortunately in our development environment there's no easy way to fix it without going through everything with a fine tooth comb.  It's on our list but very low priority.  I'll see if I can make a an example.

Comment: OK. Without seeing the actual query, sample data set, and desired result, I don't really think we can comment further.

Comment: I got it ans posted my answer thanks.

Comment: Sure, but just to note this is a kind of community, albeit a somewhat dysfunctional one. Good answers are those that (at least to some degree) benefit the community as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

the condition WHERE view_allquoteinfo.`Quote #` = t.`Quote #` inside the subqiery  is not clear ( t and view_allquoteinfo are the same table)

so try using a join on subquery group by  quote

```
SELECT
...columns...
FROM view_allQuoteInfo
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT v.`Quote #` my_quote,  max(v.Revision)  max_rev
    FROM view_allquoteinfo v
    GRUP BY v.`Quote #`
) t ON t.my_quote = view_allQuoteInfo.`Quote #`
        AND t.max_rev = view_allQuoteInfo.Revision
LEFT JOIN listcustomers c ON c.id = view_allQuoteInfo.customerId
WHERE view_allquoteinfo.customerId = 2453  
AND view_allquoteinfo.quoteStatusId = 2 
ORDER BY idx DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way that works for me.  When the user wants all quotes, I leave it the way it is.

When the user wants only the latest revisions, I modify my select query to say

`SELECT ...., MAX(view_allquoteinfo.Revision) as 'Revision',...`
and then I add a 
`GROUP BY view_allquoteinfo.'Quote #'`.